# Revert a VM client from within the VM Client - is it possible?

Tags: vmware-esxi, snapshot, vmware-vcenter

I am creating a test VM  (esxi V5) client for our QA department.

Once it's installed, my options will be:

- Use a snapshot
- Use non persistent disk on the hard disk.

For either options, I can give the role of QA_DEP the ability to log to vCenter and go back/power-off the client - so they can return to their clean machine.

My question: is it possible to have that ability without using vCenter?

What If I want that on a Client reboot - it will return to it's initial/clean state?

- The clients are not gonna be heavy loaded.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible.

However, vSphere 5 offers the ability to allow different users access to different VMs, so you could create a QA user, and only give them access to their VMs (or this VM) through the web client.  In my experience, this self-service functionality is more than enough reason to upgrade to version 5.

If that's not an option, you can set up some scripting to revert the machine to a previous snapshot on a reboot, but that's not better or easier than upgrading and enabling a self-service functionality.

Answer (score 1):

What about using the vSphere web client, typically https://:9443/admin-app.
Would this be a viable option?

Another possibilty is to install the PowerCLI and have then run a Powershell script that performs the needed tasks.

Answer (score 0):

No, but...

...does your VM technology not have client self servicing vcapabilities? The QA department should be able to do all that from the VmWare center. At least this is how it works in SCVMM from Microsoft - give users rights to a machine, they use a web based self service portal.

Comment: It's in the question: That's what the ROLE gives them the ability. I wanted to know if it can be done internally somehow